# Warning Uses Deprecated APIs

Tags: warnings, pagespeed

My [blog](https://angora.id) built in Hugo 0.100.0 with Cloudflare Pages. I got warning on [PageSpeed](https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https://angora.id) because of Uses deprecated APIs.

[image: Warning Uses Deprecated APIs]

I searched on their page but I can’t find which part I have to fix or remove. Is there any solution to fix this warning?